# Python Counter Comparison as Bag-type

Tags: python, comparison, multiset, python-collections

I need a bag/multiset-like data type in Python. I understand collections.Counter is often used for this purpose. But the comparison operators don't seem to work:

```
In [1]: from collections import Counter

In [2]: bag1 = Counter(a=1, b=2, c=3)

In [3]: bag2 = Counter(a=2, b=2)

In [4]: bag1 > bag2
Out[4]: True
```

This seems like a bug to me. I expected the less-than and greater-than operators to perform set-like subset and superset comparisons. But if that were the case then `bag1 > bag2` would be false because `bag2` contains an extra `'a'`. There also don't seem to be subset/superset methods on Counter objects. So I have two questions:

1. What comparison logic is used for Counter objects?
2. How can I compare Counter objects for subset, superset, proper-subset, and proper-superset?

Comment: Have you read the documentation?

Comment: Yes, if you mean the ones here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter They describe it as a bag/multiset, I assumed that meant the comparison operators would be meaningful.

Comment: I had not seen the linked question before and I see how it's related but it's got a couple issues: no description of how to implement proper-subset though I guess that `<=` and `!=` though I don't know if there's a better way to implement and superset though I guess that's the inverse of subset. Also the accepted answer has a typo which a comment tries to call attention to. Not sure if someone can edit that.

Comment: `set('abc')>set('ab')` is also `True`

Answer (score 2):

On Python 2, the comparison falls back to the [default sort order for dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in) (`Counter` is a subclass of `dict`).

> Mappings (dictionaries) compare equal if and only if their sorted
>   (key, value) lists compare equal. [5] Outcomes other than equality are
>   resolved consistently, but are not otherwise defined. [6]

On Python 3, [the comparison raises a `TypeError`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#not-in):

> Mappings (dictionaries) compare equal if and only if they have the
>   same (key, value) pairs. Order comparisons ('<', '<=', '>=', '>')
>   raise `TypeError`.

Comment: I'm Python 2.7, sorry forgot to mention.

Comment: Also, comparison by memory address doesn't seem to happen here: id(bag1) is 4371127560 and id(bag2) is 4371127856. So `bag2` should be greater than `bag1`.

Comment: @WilliamReed:  The ordering you are seeing is arbitrary.

Comment: will it change during the life of the Python program? Will it change from execution to execution of the Python program?

Comment: @WilliamReed:  It should not change during the life a Python program.  It *may* change from execution to execution.

Comment: It doesn't fall back to the default ordering; it falls back to the [dict implementation of `__cmp__`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/f17ab9fed3b0/Objects/dictobject.c#l1792), because `Counter` inherits from `dict`.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks for the reference. That's much more comforting than the thought that it could change between executions.

Comment: @user2357112:  Updated as such.

Comment: @WilliamReed:  user2357112 is certainly correct, but it's a small comfort.  What does it mean to say one dictionary is less than another?  In Python 2 the answer to that question is well defined, but was deemed so unuseful as to be done away with in Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

This unanswered question is of interest:

> How can I compare Counter objects for subset, superset, proper-subset, and proper-superset?

By defining the missing “rich comparison methods". You could also use free functions instead, which will make client code more explicit.

```
from collections import Counter

class PartiallyOrderedCounter(Counter):

    def __le__(self, other):
        """ Multiset inclusion """
        return all( v <= other[k] for k,v in self.items() )


    def __lt__(self, other):
        """ Multiset strict inclusion """
        return self <= other and self != other


    # TODO : __ge__ and __gt__
    # Beware : they CANNOT be written in terms of __le__ or __lt__


a = PartiallyOrderedCounter('abc')
b = PartiallyOrderedCounter('ab')
c = PartiallyOrderedCounter('abe')

assert a <= a
assert not a < a    
assert b <= a
assert b < a
assert not a < b    
assert not c <= a
assert not a <= c
```

Comment: I wonder why this doesn't come  with Counter. I can think of one application where this would be useful (cyclopeptide sequencing) and there must be others. Upvoting...

Comment: `__ge__(self, other)` can in fact be written as equivalent to `__le__(other, self)`, and similarly for `__gt__`/`__lt__`. However, `functools.total_ordering` will use `not __lt__(self. other)` for `__ge__`, which is not acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `all` to iterate over the `Counter` values, we can implement the "multiset inclusion" check like so:

```
from collections import Counter
from functools import total_ordering

class PartiallyOrderedCounter(Counter):
    def __le__(self, other):
        """ Multiset inclusion """
        test = self.copy()
        test.subtract(other)
        return not -test
    
    def __lt__(self, other):
        """ Multiset strict inclusion """
        return self <= other and self != other
```

This is probably less efficient, but interesting enough to be worth mentioning.

How it works: The `Counter`'s implementation of unary negation (as well as the binary `-` operator) negates each counter value in the result, but then also strips out everything that is negative or zero. The `.subtract` method, meanwhile, operates in place (necessitating a copy), but allows the result to have negative counts. Thus, when we negate the result from the subtraction, we get a `Counter` of only values that were "missing" from `other` (creating negative counts that were negated into positive ones). If and only if there are no such values, the [counter object is Falsey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/), and we return `True` by applying the `not` logical operator.

h/t @PM2Ring [for the technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47131116/523612).