# Why Python collections Counter does not support subset & superset comparisons?

Tags: python, comparator, multiset

This question is related to: [Python Counter Comparison as Bag-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25672738/python-counter-comparison-as-bag-type)

In Python 3, comparing two counters will result in a "TypeError: unorderable types:Counter() > Counter()".

For sets in Python, we can do things like: set1 < set2, set1 <= set2; if we treat yje Counter type as multiset, then why such comparisons are not built in the collections module? Is there any design document/PEP proposal specifying any reasons for not building in such comparisons for the Counter/multiset type in Python 3 (that is, removing such comparators from Python 2 to Python 3)?

Comment: Subset/superset comparisons are easy to do with Counters anyway. For instance, to check if `c1` is a subset of `c2` you could do something like `not c1-c2` or `all(c2[x] >= c1[x] for x in c1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Counters aren't sets, they're dicts. You can't compare dicts either:

```
>>> {1:1,2:2} < {1:1,2:2,3:3}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    {1:1,2:2}<{1:1,2:2,3:3}
TypeError: unorderable types: dict() < dict()
```

Comment: Hi Mark, Thanks for your answer/comment. Actually, as I mentioned in my question, in Python 2.7, comparison between two dicts in general, and between two counters in particular, is possible; but now in Python 3.X, such comparisons will generate TypeError. My question is: What is the logic/reason for this change from Python 2.7 to Python 3.X?

Comment: @charlesqwu in general the rules for comparing objects in Python 3 are much more restrictive that the rules in Python 2. I can't find anything about dicts specifically though. I suspect it was just because it's difficult to define a useful rule for when one dict would be less than another.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you're right - Python's `collections.Counter` does not implement the subset operators <, <=, >, >= like `set` does, although it could easily have implemented it. Other multiset implementations in Python [like this one](https://pythonhosted.org/multiset/) do implement it.

But it's fairly easy to implement this yourself. For example, here is a function checking `c1 <= c2` (c1 is a subset of c2, or equal):

```
def is_subset(c1, c2):
    return all(c1[x] <= c2[x] for x in c1)
```

What this function does it to take at all the element counts in c1, and check that the same element also exists in c2 - and in a larger or equal count.