# How to check if a word can be created from the letters in a list?

Tags: python, string, list, char

I'm trying to do something like scrabble solver.

```
letters = ['s','w','r','a']
line_of_dic= ['s','w','r','a','a']


# printing original lists
print("Original list : " + str(line_of_dic))
print("Original sub list : " + str(letters))

# using all() to
# check subset of list
flag = 0
if (all(x in line_of_dic for x in letters)):
    flag = 1

# printing result
if (flag):
    print("Yes, the word can be created")
else:
    print("No, the word cant be.")
```

This is the part of code that I'm unable to repair, word can't be created, but it prints yes. Is it possible to check if all the letters are in `line_of_dic`, but if elements are doubled or tripled to check this? Also, is it possible to do without fancy libraries?

Comment: What do you mean by **but if elements are doubled or tripled to check this** ?

Comment: `without fancy libraries` - can you use built-in python modules?

Comment: I mean that in this example the word in line of dic cant be created from the letters above, but the output here is that it can be.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer OP wants to only return Yes if the same count of each character from `line_of_dic` is present in `letters`. They want to be able to build the contents of `line_of_dic` from `letters`.

Comment: @wwii yes, i can use them

Comment: @RandomDavis Yes, I created script that read values and changes them into a list with chars from the txt file that contains dictonary. My point is to be able to check if word can be created from letters or not

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25672738

Comment: Should we use all of the letters in the reference list, or can we skip some?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done on one line by comparing the count of each letter:

```
flag = 0
if all(line_of_dic.count(char) == letters.count(char) for char in line_of_dic):
    flag = 1
```

Rather than checking if the letter is present, this checks if the count matches.

Comment: Wonderful solution, Thank you for help

Answer (score 1):

You can use dictionary structure. To create dictionary from list you can write a simple code:

```
letterDict = {}
lineDict = {}

for item in letters:
    if item not in letterDict:
        letterDict[item] = 1
    else:
        letterDict[item] += 1
        
for item in line_of_dic:
    if item not in lineDict:
        lineDict[item] = 1
    else:
        lineDict[item] += 1
```

After that point, you can simply compare two dictionary:

```
if letterDict == lineDict:
    print("Yes, the word can be created")
else:
    print("No, the word cant be.")
```

Comment: Thank you for solution

Answer (score 0):

You need to count the number of each character in each *word* and then compare the values.  You can do this with a dictionary.

```
ltrs = {}
lod = {}

for char in letters:
    ltrs[char] = ltrs.get(char,0) + 1

for char in line_of_dic:
    lod[char] = lod.get(char,0) + 1
```

Then you can see if there are enough of each character to make the word.

```
In [3]: ltrs
Out[3]: {'a': 1, 'r': 1, 's': 1, 'w': 1}

In [4]: lod
Out[4]: {'a': 2, 'r': 1, 's': 1, 'w': 1}
```

---

[collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) can make those dictionaries for you.

```
import collections
ltrs = collections.Counter(letters)
lod = collections.Counter(line_of_dic)

In [6]: ltrs
Out[6]: Counter({'a': 1, 'r': 1, 's': 1, 'w': 1})

In [7]: lod
Out[7]: Counter({'a': 2, 'r': 1, 's': 1, 'w': 1})
```

Subtracting the Counters you can see if there are enough.

```
In [31]: lod-ltrs
Out[31]: Counter({'a': 1})
```

`lod` has one more `'a'` than `ltrs`.